# How does gpu acceleration work for instructions mot in GPU

Tags: pytorch, gpu, instruction-set

I’ve heard that gpus can only compute simple instructions but do them in a parallel matter, which makes them suited for machine learning.

What happens if a pytorch tensor is in gpu but the type of computation I want to perform is not included in the gpu’s instruction set? Does the data in vram travel to the cpu for that specific computation?

Comment: what type of operation do you have in mind? most "complex" operations can be executed by a series of simpler ones

Comment: thank you for the answer! I was thinking, any type of complex operation that would not be sufficient with a GPU? I was just wondering how packages such as pytorch run..

Comment: I think I'm struggling with a similar issue to what you're describing and I'm getting the error "RuntimeError: Unable to find a valid cuDNN algorithm to run convolution". Might be wrong though.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.